# Where do I download PHP extensions for windows?

Tags: php, postgresql, php-extension

I'm trying to make my PHP installation to work with PostgreSQL, so I need  php_pgsql.dll

A very dumb question, but where do I get one for my PHP5.3?

I have read here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php, but it is said that, yes, you need this dll, but no download link. What am I missing?

dll is not present by default in my installation:

[image]

Comment: The [official binaries](http://windows.php.net/download/) have the driver included. If yours is not the official distribution (the "/usr/local/php5" folder looks suspicious) you have to ask wherever you've downloaded it from. Or use the official one.

Comment: @Milen A. Radev, looks like you are right. I found what I have been looking for at http://www.denwer.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extension is in ext subdirectory, to activate it you have to edit php.ini, set ext dir and uncomment php_pgsql

Comment: You should download php from php.net ( http://www.php.net/downloads.php ) It has all extensions.